# Do I need to recreate bindings, if the native framework changes?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I made an implementation change to one of the methods in the native framework. Would I need to recreate bindings, in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: likely not

Long answer: Depends, you would need to rebuild the binding only if this change you mention is in the public API signature of the method / property. This is because the bindings matches 1 : 1 (most of the time) what the native API surfaces so for example if your method used to return a `NSString` and now it returns another class or the selector name changes or the type of any of the parameters changes then yes.

You also would need to rebuild the binding if the binding dll bundles the native library you are using. If you are manually linking the native library (using the additional touch args in your app project) you should be fine.